# Hidden Field not passing value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**This is myModel**

```
public class myModel : myBaseModel
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string BranchCode { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the AccountName,BankName and BranchCode from the view with textBoxFor

```
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountName, GetContentBody(101111))
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountName)
```

**Problem is** I dont need the Accountname text box anymore, however I am not allowed to remove AccountName from the model and I should assign this value in the view.

So I **planned to change this textbox with html.hiddenFor** with its value, the problem is hiddenfield is passing the account name to the controller as a null.

****my question is why hiddenfield is passing its value as a null?****

**I removed this**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName)
```

**and added instead of it**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AccountName, new { @Value = "defaultUserName" });
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking? If you are not using / do not want `AccountName` then why it a problem if it is null? If you really ARE using it and want it to be a hidden field then why not show us your code with it as hidden so we can see it without guessing what you have done?

Comment: Why not showing code with `html.hiddenFor` when problem is there?

Comment: The hidden-field will get the value you set it when you return the model on creation. If you set it as null, it will send back as null on the post. Either give it a value on creation, or change it with JS.

Comment: I removed the textbox but I will insert the account name automatically, without waiting with user input, so I can reach the account name from the view, assigning it to hiddenfields value but, it is passing controller as a null

Comment: Show us new code with hidden field.

Comment: I added the code for hidden field

Comment: This code will not compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing wrong. you have to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object%29) or [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) for it, it looks like you missed a comma to separate the extension method arguments:

Instead of:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AccountName new { @Value = "defaultUserName" })
```

you need to do:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AccountName, new { @Value = "defaultUserName" })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 <input type="hidden" value="@Model.AccountName" name="AccountName" />
```

you have to give name to your control because that's how mvc maps.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you can replace for `<input type="hidden" value="@Model.AccountName" />`

If your Model was populated, will works fine!

Comment: Need to supply `name="AccountName"` in the `input` too... `<input type="hidden" value="@Model.AccountName" name="AccountName" />`

Answer (score 0):

When u pass Html Helper Controls value to Controller's method using parameter, 
u must supply name property of that html helper in 
like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AccountName, new { @Value = "defaultUserName" , name = "hiddenname" })
```

and in controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string hiddenname){}
```

this will catch ur view hidden value